# Build sphinx documentation in local with pdf download option

Tags: pdf, documentation, local, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I would like to build in local my documentation using sphinx and let the user the possibility to download it in .pdf file.

In many documentations I found there are this:
[image]

In the readTheDoc theme. But after many search, i can t find the extension that enable this:

[image]

Did an expert tell me how to modify my `conf.py` or my `sphinx-build command` to enable this feature?

I saw the file .readthedoc.yml containing:

```
formats:
  - pdf
```

But how to run it from local ? I have created my `.readthedocs.yml` from [documentation:](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html#formats):

```
version: 1

# Build documentation in the docs/ directory with Sphinx
sphinx:
  builder: html
  configuration: doc/external_doc/source/conf.py

formats: all
```

Which command can i use to run this without a server?

Comment: Thank you for answer, i will have a look on rinoh to generate in .pdf!

Comment: did you find any working solution for your problem?

Comment: not for the moment...